# NumberFormatException not being caught

Tags: java, object, exception

I'm out of Ideas, I don't know why these exceptions aren't being caught but the `ArithmeticException` is. It should catch the exception if there is no input for numerator or denominator right? Any assistance would be appreciated I've been ripping my hair out trying to get these exception classes to work.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {

        String numText = numFld.getText();
        String denText = denFld.getText();

        if(ev.getActionCommand().equals("Build Fraction"))
        {

            numFld.setText("");
            denFld.setText("");

            int numerator = Integer.parseInt(numText);  
            int denominator = Integer.parseInt(denText);

            try {
                System.out.println(numerator);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnlOne, "Numerator cannot be empty");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                numFld.requestFocus();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println(denominator);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnlOne, "Denominator cannot be empty");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                denFld.requestFocus();
            }

            try {
                System.out.println(numerator/denominator);
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pnlOne, "Denominator cannot be 0");
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                denFld.requestFocus();
            }

            if (denominator !=0 && numText!="" && denText!="") {
            Fraction fraction = new Fraction(numerator,denominator);
            fractions.add(fraction);
            fractionFld.append(fraction.getNum() + "/" + fraction.getDen() + "\n\r");
            }

        }
```

Comment: What type of View do you use as `numFld` and `denFld`? Also could you post crash log?

Comment: numfld and textfld is a JTextPane
https://i.imgur.com/hvk4gtJ.png

Answer (score 0):

You have the crash because you try to catch it after it happened, you should put the following code `Integer.parseInt(numText)` inside of `try{}` block:

```
     int numerator = 0;  
     int denominator = 0;

     try {
        numerator = Integer.parseInt(numText);  
        denominator = Integer.parseInt(denText);
     } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
         //handle error
     }
```

Comment: but then how will I use the numerator and denominator variables outside the catch statement

Comment: @SeePlus you may init them outside of try-catch block but you have to parse them inside of try block.

Comment: @SeePlus have I answered your question?

Comment: Thank you for your help, and thank you for checking in with me after some time to see how it went :)